# react v15 PropTypes and CreateClass

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

As I'm using `PropTypes` from the `react.js` library and `CreateClass` i'm a bit worried that those 2 are deprecated on the next major version of `react.js`.

After updating to react v15 I'm getting the warnings about it. I've read that there is a script that can auto refactor it (extracting `PropTypes` to the new library) but can't find it now.

anyone tried that script and can share his / her experience with it? (and know where can i find it of course)

And how safe is it to keep my current syntax? what are the downsides beside losing the ability to migrate to v16 (fiber)

Comment: Please have a look at the official blog post:
https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html
They have extracted `React.PropTypes` and `React.createClass` into their own packages to keep the core library smaller. You can migrate to React 16 by using [`create-react-class`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-class) and [`prop-types`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types).

Comment: thanks, i will read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`react-codemod`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod) which utilizes [`jscodeshift`](https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift).

I just ran through this the other day, and here's the distilled version of what you'd need to do:

1. Install `jscodeshift` globally:

   - `npm install -g jscodeshift`
2. Clone the `react-codemod` repository:

   - `git clone https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod.git`
3. Install the dependencies for `react-codemod`:

   - `cd ./react-codemod`
   - `npm install`
4. Change directories to your project:

   - `cd ../my-project`
5. Execute the code shift by specifying a transformation file:

   - Say we want to fix `PropTypes`, and our components are located in `/my-project/src`

     - `jscodeshift -t ../react-codemod/transforms/React-PropTypes-to-prop-types.js ./src`
6. To also include JSX extensions, use the `extensions` options:

   `jscodeshift -t ../react-codemod/transforms/React-PropTypes-to-prop-types.js ./src --extensions js,jsx`

If all goes well, you should see `jscodeshift` processing N files:

[image]